# python manage.py runserver, shell, dbshell freezes on git-bash

Tags: python, django, windows, git-bash

I'm trying to run the interactive shell in python virtualenv in windows, on git-bash, but it isn't running. Strange thing is, it doesn't seem to do anything, just the cursor is blinking on the next line, giving no output.

```
$ python manage.py shell
|
```

However, I'm able to run commands like - migrate, makemigrations, sqlmigrate. Problem is occurring with the commands - shell, dbshell, runserver.

This seems to be some git-bash related issue, because I'm able to run shell from command line. I'm using [`PortableGit-2.4.3.1-2nd-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.3.1-2nd-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe) on windows.

Comment: Have you tried? `python manage.py shell_plus --ipython`

Comment: @dabad No module named IPython. I'm not using IPython BTW.

Comment: I guess simply `python manage.py shell_plus` does not work right?

Comment: @dabad Nope. That doesn't. But it shows some output regarding deprecation.

Comment: If I have problems with hung programs, I usually try [PyStuck](https://github.com/alonho/pystuck) on them...  Can you get any stack output from that to show what's going on?

Comment: @PeterBrittain Well, I installed PyStuck, and IPython also got installed with it, with which it's working.

Comment: OK, so that path won't help...  Does it still reproduce without pystuck or has the IPython installation fixed your issue?

Comment: @PeterBrittain Actually with IPython, the issue seems to be resolved.

Comment: Weird.  I wonder if there's any undeclared dependency in there...  Writing up what we've found as a formal answer.  Let me know if there's anything else you think I should put in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarising the investigation in the comments...

A good way to investigate these sorts of problems is to use [pystuck](https://github.com/alonho/pystuck).

In this case, it would appear to have been some sort of internal dependency on IPython as installing pystuck also installs IPython and the bug no longer reproduces with Both installed.

Comment: Well, I'll accept this answer for now, as it got me moving ahead with my work at least.. Still have to see why it didn't work with built-in python interpreter. Will play around with pystuck when I get some time. Meanwhile, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @Rohit Jain: Yeah - it's less than satisfactory to me too, so I had a quick look at the [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8047e3666b0b50bb04e6f16c2a4fb21ddfd5713f/django/core/management/commands/shell.py). Looks like IPython will be used in preference to bpython and then ultimately the code module. My guess is that you have a dodgy bpython installation.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is python.exe itself has issues with gitbash. Supposedly, it has something to do with the ncurses library.

The solution is to type "winpty python.exe" instead of python. "winpty python.exe manage.py shell" should work. You can also create an alias to bypass the issue. Typing "alias python='winpty python.exe'" will make it so "python manage.py shell" works as it should.

This answer explains it better:
[Python not working in the command line of git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have idea for the commands `shell`, and `dbshell`, but for  `runserver`command, I had same issue. I solved running

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and refresh the browser. Your terminal must show the info of your website

Answer (score 0):

If you go to  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ you will see it is working fine