# Running Django development server from Git Bash gets stuck in windows 10

Tags: python, django, manage.py

I'm new to Django and now getting stuck in running up the server. I've installed the following components on Windows 10:

```
Python 3.7.0
Django 1.11.14
Geckodriver 0.21.0
```

I can successfully create a project using     `django-admin.py startproject {project_name} .`
but when I run     `python manage.py runserver`, the Git Bash doesn't seem to make any progress and the process gets stuck there forever.

```
$ python manage.py runserver
|
```

I'm supposed to get something like the following output though,

> Performing system checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
>
> Django version 1.8.3, using settings 'projectname.settings' Starting >development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

I've also activated the `virtualenv` too. What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: You might want to refer to this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029068/python-manage-py-runserver-shell-dbshell-freezes-on-git-bash)

Comment: Can you once try in Powershell or command prompt

Comment: When I tried in powershell, it returns `SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized`

Comment: Did you find a solution, I am having simialr issue

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash

Answer (score 1):

Thing is when you run `python manage.py runserver` by default it will run with **auto reload**.

Means when you change any file it will re-run or relaod again where it might be needed to kill and start port `e.g 8080`.

Unfortunately `GitBash` is more lighter one which is not capable to kill process.Have one workaround to run with not **auto reload**. like below:

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Comment: I tried with that command but it now returns SyntaxError instead of the cursor blinking.

Comment: Ah actually had same issue 3 year ago and I tried like this. But instead of gitbash try powershell then.

Comment: Tried with both command prompt & powershell but it returns the same SyntaxError too.

Comment: This is the ending part of the error `from django.contrib.admin.filters import (
  File "D:\kz\python\python-tdd-book\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\widgets.py", line 152
    '%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items(),
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized`

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48822656/5722054) says there's a problem between Django and python 3.7. So I ended up installing python 3.6 and things are working as expected after that.

Answer (score 0):

I also think you should try using the windows command prompt instead

Comment: Trying in command prompt also returns `SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized`

Answer (score 0):

**Quite literally exit bash, reopen bash, and run your server** it will no longer hang. I had the same issue anytime I made changes to my server database configuration(make/run migrations). I can't root cause it, it may be a linux running inside windows thing, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It works by

```
winpty python manage.py runserver
```

You can add an alias to your `.bashrc` by

```
echo "alias python='winpty python.exe'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash)